# Using Google Sign in android with multiples backend servers

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have multiple websites (with different domains) and each has a Google project in my `Google Developer API Console`.
I have only one `Android app` that uses all those websites, and i want to add Google Sign in to the android app.

I want to authenticate the user in my backend by requesting a token:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestServerAuthCode(Configuration.getGoogleServerID())
                    .build();`
```

Thing is i can only sign in using the `Server_Client_ID` of one of those Google projects. Google does not allow to create an Android OAuth Client ID for more than one project. It will say that the Fingerprint of the app is already in use.

How can i login my mobile users in my websites?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also searching for the same. Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to have all those websites and mobile app within a single project. This is permitted in Firebase. In this way, all your users (web or mobile) can sign in without any problems.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried importing the projects to firebase. But again, you can only add ONE android (package+SHA1 fingerprint) app to one project. There is a Whitelisting feature  for ClientIDs on the Google Sign In options in Firebase but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Herno, did you try removing the SHA1 fingerprint from your Firebase configuration? Did you ever solve the problem?